# Grep all files from samba

Tags: linux, grep, smb, smbclient

I'm transferring some files using samba. I use this command

```
smbclient '//MICROSOF-14656A/Shared' -c 'lcd /mnt/transfer/;cd Directory; get file.txt'
```

But I get tired to move one file by one. There is a way to grep all files and all directories from Shared ? I tried to google, but didn't find anything that work.

This command is good too

```
smbclient '//MICROSOF-14656A/Shared' -c 'lcd /mnt/transfer/; mget *'
```

but it don't save folders

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *tar* archive:

```
cd /mnt/transfer &&
smbclient //MICROSOF-14656A/Shared -Tc files.tar '*' &&
tar xf files.tar &&
rm files.tar
```